# Печать отдельного блока страницы

Tags: html, печать

Как реализоватьв HTML печать нужного блока страницы, а не всей страницы?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 5):

Обратите внимание в сторону css свойства [media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media), а именно его типа `print`, который указывает стили для печати.
Вот неплохая статья на эту тему: [тыц](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/qt/block_print.htm)